# How to pass yaml parameter to another yaml params

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a parameterized rmarkdown and I need to pass the "Year:" parameter to the "Dates:" value: parameter. Currently, the yaml is hardcoded but I need the Year: to be included in the sliderInput dynamically.

```
---
title: "Salmon Program"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date())`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
    keep_md: yes
params:
  glimpse: no
  Runs:
    label: Salmon Runs
    value:
    - Winter
    - Spring
    - Fall
    - LateFall
    input: select
    choices:
    - Winter
    - Spring
    - Fall
    - LateFall
    multiple: yes
  Year: 2012        #How to pass this parameter to the Dates: value below?
  Dates:
    input: slider
    min: !r as.Date("2012-01-01")
    max: !r as.Date("2012-12-31")
    value: !r c(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-04")) #Pass Year:2012 here to update sliderInput
    step: 30
---
```